# Does Principal Component Regression still work in high-dimensional ($N<p$) situation?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

I understand that, many classical methods for multiple regression won't work when $N<p$, where $p$ is the dimension of the input space and $N$ is the sample size.

For example, LSE for multiple regression, if $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ is nonsingular, then the unique solution is given by $\hat\beta=(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}$. But if $p>N$, $\mathbf{X}_{N\times p}$ cannot be of full column rank, thus $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ is singular and the parameters in the regression model cannot be uniquely estimated.

Now, my confusion is, Principal Component Regression is also a popular classical regression method for high-dimensional data, but will there be any problem, like above, when we apply PCR to a high-dimensional ($n\ll p$) data?

More specifically, if $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ is singular, how to calculate the principal components? (How to make the eigen decomposition for a singular matrix?) Are the principal components given by softwares still correct? Can we still regress on these principal components for dimension reduction purpose?

Could anybody give me a hint? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm alsways doing is to do a "robust" cholesky-decomposition and then an iterative Jacobi-rotation to the principal components. "Robust" means here, that missing/low rank is handled in the same sense as zero-eigenvalues in the "pseudo-inverse" computation. So that "robust" cholesky decomposition gives a reduced set of components, which can then be made orthogonal by a column-wise rotation.
With a rank-3 random correlationmatrix r
$$  \text{ R =} \small \left[ \begin{array} {rrrrrr} 
  1.0000& -0.8790& -0.8389& -0.8184& -0.5239& -0.7192\\
 -0.8790&  1.0000&  0.6751&  0.5508&  0.0846&  0.3115\\
 -0.8389&  0.6751&  1.0000&  0.9721&  0.7127&  0.7833\\
 -0.8184&  0.5508&  0.9721&  1.0000&  0.8534&  0.9053\\
 -0.5239&  0.0846&  0.7127&  0.8534&  1.0000&  0.9633\\
 -0.7192&  0.3115&  0.7833&  0.9053&  0.9633&  1.0000
     \end{array} \right] $$
I get by the "robust" cholesky-decomposition the loadings-matrix $L$ with only 3 significant columns $ L = cholesky(R)$ 
$$  \text{ L =} \small \left[ \begin{array} {rrrrrr} 
  1.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000\\
 -0.8790&  0.4767&  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000\\
 -0.8389& -0.1308&  0.5283&  0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000\\
 -0.8184& -0.3536&  0.4530& -0.0000&  0.0000&  0.0000\\
 -0.5239& -0.7886&  0.3218&  0.0000& -0.0000&  0.0000\\
 -0.7192& -0.6727&  0.1742& -0.0000& -0.0000&  0.0000
     \end{array} \right]  $$
and by iterative columnwise jacobi-rotation on the first 3 nonzero axes $  P=\operatorname{rot}(L,\text{"PCA"})$ the principal components-solution
$$  \text{ P =} \small \left[ \begin{array} {rrr} 
  0.9037& -0.3761&  0.2045\\
 -0.6478&  0.7610& -0.0363\\
 -0.9557&  0.0870&  0.2812\\
 -0.9832& -0.1061&  0.1482\\
 -0.8119& -0.5821& -0.0446\\
 -0.9087& -0.3731& -0.1871
     \end{array} \right]$$
At the moment I do not exactly how to proceed to the regression-step - perhaps please give a hint how your model of dependent/independent variables is thought to be organized.

Comment: What I mean by Principal Component Regression is: suppose we have $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{V} \mathbf{D}^2\mathbf{V}$, principal component regression forms the derived input columns $\mathbf{z}_m=\mathbf{X}v_m$ and then regresses $\mathbf{y}$ on $\mathbf{z}_1, \cdots, \mathbf{z}_M$ for some $M\leq p$. Because $\mathbf{z}_m$ are orthogonal, This regression is just a sum of univariate regressions.